# Minecraft not starting: "Please Fix Error and Restart"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I deleted the .minecraft folder because I wanted to uninstall it and now when I try to open the Minecraft launcher it gives me the following message: please fix error and restart.

My .minecraft folder is empty and I know for a fact that this is causing the problem but I don't know how to redownload the files that belong in .minecraft. I tried downloading Minecraft afterwards but the same thing happens. When I delete the .minecraft folder, the launcher makes a new one but it is always empty.

Comment: Which launcher are you using? I cannot reproduce the problem: when I delete my .minecraft folder, the official launcher starts fine, it asks me to login since my stored credentials are gone, and then it says "Ready to download & play Minecraft 1.6.2" in the bottom right. Are you maybe using the old launcher, or a third-party launcher like Magic Launcher?

Comment: Also: have you recently installed or uninstalled Java, or applied any system updates to your computer? Some googling indicates that "Please fix error and restart" can be caused by the official launcher tring to use a broken Java install to connect to the internet to download Minecraft's files.

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first, make sure you have Java, it doesn't have to be the latest build as on my Gaming PC i haven't updated Java since Minecraft first came out and it's been fine (apart from a notice saying i need 64-bit java for a full render distance) but it's best to get the latest build just in case, if you do have java update it, the problem could be your Java installation and an update would fix that, otherwise uninstall and reinstall java

Second, if your reinstalling Minecraft, make sure you're online, while you can play Minecraft offline that's only after you've downloaded the files, while i haven't upgraded to 1.6.2 (because i would have to regenerate the world to update it and i'm waiting on the new biomes in 1.7 before i go though that) i'm assuming you can still play it offline just by failing to login and selecting "Play Offline". if you can't connect to the internet on your computer you can just run Minecraft on a computer connected to the net to download the files and then copy your .minecraft folder onto a memory stick and transfer it to your offline computer

if you're still getting an error, redownload the Miecraft.exe, i do remember that if you was using the old launcher it wont automatically update to the newer one and you had to download the new launcher manually however that's easy to do since you can just log into your account on the website and redownload it since you are using a legitimate copy

Comment: They must have Java, else the launcher won't start. You also don't need to regenerate the world to have all the features 1.6.2 coming from 1.5.1. You're right that not being connected to the internet might be causing this, though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i was just saying they need java but it doesn't have to be the latest one since i havn't updated java at all on my computer since installing it, as for regenerating the world you would if you already had deserts and Neather Fortresses already created, if you don't then it's ok since you'll get the updated stuff when you generate new chunks

Comment: Oh, you mean the change to water in deserts? That's fairly minor though. And Nether fortresses have been in for a while now and haven't changed in 1.6.2. The worldgen changes in 1.6.x are very, very minor. (And you start by saying "make sure you have Java". They definitely have Java. Maybe word that differently then.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Neather Fortresses did change by having loot cheats generated in them, i doubt they would automatically be added in there after an update given the fact someone (like me) has modified one to be easier to access and more protection against Ghast attack when outside, as for the deserts, it wouldn't feel right to have something built from a river in the desert if they no longer should be in there

Comment: Oh! I stand well corrected. I didn't know that the loot chests were a new feature. As you were, and my apologies. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know how to fix it if you have ESET antivirus is causing problems.

Go to the antivirus and click options, then Advanced Settings. Then go to HTTP and HTTPS and choose "Don't check HTTPS protocol" and click apply. This worked for me

Comment: This seems like a pretty specific situation. Antiviruses usually don't block all internet, and if they do, disabling them completely probably isn't a good idea if you don't replace them with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error saying "Please Fix and restart", what I did to fix that problem was uninstall Java, then re-download the program. This should work for most  of you with the problem like I had. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by"Uninstall Java" and then "re-Download" the program? Do you mean uninstall Java then re-install it, or re-install Minecraft. If you can fix that, then it will make it much easier to understand.